# How can i fix python pandas mysql syntax error?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas

I have the code below for migration from mysql to postgresql.

```
def get_mysql_connection(database_name: Optional[str] = None) -> MysqlConnection:
    if database_name is None:
        database_name = ""
    return pymysql.connect(host=DB_HOST, port=int(3306), user=MYSQL_DB_USER, passwd=password, db=MYSQL_DB_NAME)
 
 
def create_mysql_database(connection: MysqlConnection) -> None:
    # create mysql database
    connection.cursor().execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {};".format(MYSQL_DB_NAME))
    connection.cursor().execute("CREATE DATABASE {};".format(MYSQL_DB_NAME))
    connection.close()
 
 
def get_postgresql_connection(database_name: Optional[str] = None) -> PostgresConnection:
    if database_name is None:
        database_name = "postgres"
    engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{POSTGRESQL_DB_USER}:{password}@{DB_HOST}/{database_name}', echo=False,
                           isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
    return engine.connect()
 
 
def create_postgres_database(connection: PostgresConnection) -> None:
    connection.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {};".format(POSTGRESQL_DB_NAME))
    connection.execute("CREATE DATABASE {};".format(POSTGRESQL_DB_NAME))
    connection.close()
 
def migrate_data_from_mysql_to_postgres(mysql_conn: MysqlConnection, postgres_conn: PostgresConnection) -> None:
 
    tables_mysql = pd.read_sql_query("""SHOW TABLES""", mysql_conn)
 
    for table in tables_mysql["""Tables_in_{}""".format(MYSQL_DB_NAME)]:
        query = f"""SELECT * FROM '{table}'"""
        table_chunks = pd.read_sql_query(query, mysql_conn, chunksize=100)
 
        for chunk in table_chunks:
            table_cols = chunk.columns
 
            new_col_names = []
            for col_name in table_cols:
                new_col_names.append(to_camel_case(col_name))
            chunk.columns = new_col_names
 
            print(chunk.columns)
            print('====')
 
            # load chunk into postgresql database
            chunk.to_sql('{}'.format(table), con=postgres_conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
 
 
def main() -> None:
    mysql_conn = get_mysql_connection()
 
    create_mysql_database(mysql_conn)
 
    mysql_conn = get_mysql_connection(MYSQL_DB_NAME)
 
    load_data_dump("ex-str.sql", mysql_conn)
 
    postgres_conn = get_postgresql_connection()
 
    create_postgres_database(postgres_conn)
 
    postgres_conn = get_postgresql_connection(POSTGRESQL_DB_NAME)
 
    migrate_data_from_mysql_to_postgres(mysql_conn, postgres_conn)
```

Im running this code on ubuntu 18.04 with python3.8 and mysql 14.
I got an error message like:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''<style>\\r\\n\\r\\nbody {\\r\\n\tbackground: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e,' at line 1")
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by where. I run my program and it gives me that error. I didnt understand where its come from

Comment: When it gives you the error, it says in wich line of code is thecerror, so you can find a solution. You shouldctake a look at what kind of data you have in your chunk DF in your migrate function

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 162, in <module>
    main() first line say that

Comment: And what makes you think that we know what is the line 162 in your code?? You have to make an effort to help us help you. What we need to know is wich was the line that forced the error, and as It was a MySql query, we need to know what was that query (because it has a sintax error) . Otherways, there is no way for us to help you

Comment: In line 162, i have if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(). Because of that i didnt guess where is the error